# Test Driven Development :: AndroidStudio + Robolectric(Can not resolve symbol error for junit and Robolectric imports)

Tags: android, tdd, robolectric

I had searched on the web how to configure robolectric with android studio.

**There is plenty material on web but none worked for me. Everyone has their own steps to configure Robolectric with android studio.**

I specifically want to do **Test Driven Development** in android studio. There is no standard way of configuring Robolectric with android studio.
Can anyone explain step by step why configuration with android studio?

Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19

    }
    productFlavors {
        India_Production {
        }
        India_Staging {
            packageName 'com.infibeam.allthingsd.apps.spinr.india_stage'
        }
        Indonesia_Prod {
        }
        Indonesia_Stag {
            packageName 'com.infibeam.allthingsd.apps.spinr.indonesia_stage'
        }
    } 

    sourceSets{
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }

}

dependencies {
    /* compile project(':External_Jars')*/
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'External_Jars', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile  'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.+'
    testCompile  'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend starting off with [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) - a template project which is pre-configured for you (don't forget the Setup instructions though). In my experience, Android Studio + Gradle doesn't play well with Robolectic, so I would also recommend using IntelliJ instead.

Alternatively, if you are willing to switch to Maven instead of Gradle, then you can use [deckard-maven](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-maven) instead - which does work well with Android Studio.